# WIFI issues on Boot, wpasupplicant failed to start on boot

Tags: raspbian, wifi

Device : Raspberry pi 2
Os: Raspbian Debian Wheezy (kernel 3.18)

I tried to implement the following instructables DIY :

http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Internet-Monitor/?ALLSTEPS

Added my python file in the format "post-up python /home/pi/python_programs/rpi-internet-monitor.py" to /etc/network/interfaces.
The functionality works on python shell and even during boot. My problem is that WIFI is not loading on Boot. Once it is booted, it gets connected automatically, however for my application it needs to be available on boot.

On boot I get the message

```
"Configuring network interfaces... 
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1 "
```

Attaching the image for the same.

But after boot it works with no issues. I am new to pi and linux. Really appreciate if anyone could help me with the same.
Have not tried with ethernet, no LAN availability as of now.

[image: wpa supplicant failed on boot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the latest Raspbian image which is using `dhcpcd`.

> For an updated solution See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

This is a misguided/half-baked attempt to make it easier to setup WiFi via the GUI, unfortunately it failed to consider those who use the command line.

The good news is that the "errors" are not a problem, and can be safely ignored. I think it would have been better that the release deactivated the startup services which are not used.